# How do I get the last update time of a sequence of tables in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

A BigQuery best practice is to split timeseries in daily tables (as "NAME_yyyyMMdd") and then use Table Wildcards to query one or more of these tables.

Sometimes it is useful to get the last update time on a certain set of data (i.e. to check correctness of the ingestion procedure). How do I get the last update time over a set of tables organized like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT *
FROM `project_name.data_set_name`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS
where table_name='my_table';

[Solution for Google](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#columns_view)

Comment: Thank you @Stas_Shch for the update! Yes, it will be the preferred approach as soon as the PARTITIONS table goes GA. I will set yours as the correct answer!

Answer (score 3):

A good way to achieve that is to use the `__TABLES__` meta-table. Here is a generic query I use in several projects:

```
SELECT
  MAX(last_modified_time) LAST_MODIFIED_TIME,
  IF(REGEXP_MATCH(RIGHT(table_id,8),"[0-9]{8}"),LEFT(table_id,LENGTH(table_id) - 8),table_id) AS TABLE_ID
FROM
  [my_dataset.__TABLES__]
GROUP BY
  TABLE_ID
```

It will return the last update time of every table in `my_dataset`. For tables organized with a daily-split structure, it will return a single value (the update time of the latest table), with the initial part of their name as `TABLE_ID`.

Comment: It won't work if you have the bad idea of calling your tables like "heres_a_few_useless_digits_01234567".

Comment: Note that meta-table use is only recommended up to a few thousand tables within a dataset per https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#meta-tables. Also note that `__TABLES_SUMMARY__` is faster than `__TABLES__` and should be used whenever possible.

Comment: Good to know, thank you @MichaelSheldon! In this case `__TABLES_SUMMARY__` cannot be used as it does not contain the `last_modified_time` field, but I will remember your advice for those cases in which the choice is possible.